# Amazon Alexa Entity Resolutions: Is it possible to have more than one AuthoritiesPerResolution?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

When you have an entity resolution (slot-filling with SlotTypes that have the same synonyms) , how many **AuthoritiesPerResolution** are you able to have?

Is there any case where having multiple AuthoritiesPerResolution is **possible?**

What are the scenarios and conditions to get **more than one** AuthoritiesPerResolution?

Comment: your SlotTypes are different, with same synonyms? Why would you have something like that? Won't it be ambiguous for Alexa?